# Transform a button submit into an icon

Tags: php, forms, symfony, symfony4, symfony-3.4

I have a list of items shown to the user and I want for him to have a small "button" (in fact, I prefer an icon). To be sure we won't be able to delete every file by a loop, I want a form to delete it.

So, in my index action, I created a form by item :

```
/**
 * @Route("/files", name="files")
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 */

public function files() {
    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository("App:Document");
    $files = $repository->findBy([], ["createdAt" => "DESC"]);

    $forms = [];
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        $forms[$file->getId()] = $this->createForm(DocumentRemoveType::class, $file)->createView();
    }

    return $this->render("admin/files.html.twig", [
        "files" => $files,
        "forms" => $forms
    ]);
}
```

Then, in my twig view, I show each form :

```
{% for file in files %}
            {# @var file \App\Entity\Document #}
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">{{ file.name }}</th>
            <td>{{ file.createdAt|date("d/m/Y") }}</td>
            <td class="text-center">
                <a href="{{ vich_uploader_asset(file, 'file') }}" target="_blank" title="Télécharger le document"><i class="fa fa-download"></i></a>
                {{ form_start(forms[file.id], {attr: {class: 'my-form-class'} }) }}
                    {{ form_widget(forms[file.id]) }}
                {{ form_end(forms[file.id]) }}
            </td>
        </tr>
 {% endfor %}
```

Then, here's the DocumentRemoveType

```
class DocumentRemoveType extends AbstractType
{
    private $urlGenerator;

    public function __construct(UrlGeneratorInterface $urlGenerator)
    {
        $this->urlGenerator = $urlGenerator;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add("id", HiddenType::class)
            ->setAction($this->urlGenerator->generate("admin_files_deletion"))
            ->add("removeButton", SubmitType::class);
    }
}
```

And finally, here's the action for the deletion :

```
/**
 * @Route("/files/delete", name="admin_files_deletion")
 * @param Request $request
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse
 */
public function filesDeletion(Request $request) {
    $form = $this->createForm(DocumentRemoveType::class);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $manager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $file = $manager->find(Document::class, $manager["id"]);

        $manager->remove($file);
        $manager->flush();
    }
    return $this->redirectToRoute('admin_files');
}
```

To be honest, I'm not really sure if I follow the good path.
At the moment, this works BUT I would like to have a small pictogram instead of this ugly input button.
Do you know how I should do this?

If you noticed something wrong in the code have, don't hesitate to notice me.

Comment: Are you simply asking about how you can have an icon as a button? That's a HTML/CSS question.

Comment: Not really, because I have to use a SubmitType, isn't it?

Comment: Not really. It is not mandatory to use SubmitType. In fact the recommendation is to use plain html in such cases

Comment: And about the code above, is it the good way to do it? So, you're saying that I should just use CSS to have what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comments, I understood I just had to add the button directly in the view :

```
{% for file in files %}
            {# @var file \App\Entity\Document #}
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">{{ file.name }}</th>
            <td>{{ file.createdAt|date("d/m/Y") }}</td>
            <td class="text-center">
                {{ form_start(forms[file.id], { "attr" : { "onsubmit" : "return confirm('Êtes-vous certain de supprimer ce document?');"}}) }}
                    <a href="{{ vich_uploader_asset(file, 'file') }}" target="_blank" title="Télécharger le document"><i class="fa fa-download"></i></a>
                    <button type="submit" class="buttonAsLink"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></button>
                    {{ form_widget(forms[file.id]) }}
                {{ form_end(forms[file.id]) }}
            </td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
```

And I removed the SubmitType in my form.
Everything works as expected now.

Thank you everyone